# how to find out which key is free to use in a specific mode-map?

Tags: key-bindings

Suppose I'd like to add a custom key bind to a certain mode map.

I don't want to override an existing key accidently.
How can I find out which keys are free to use for a mode-map?

The best way I can think of is to actually open a buffer with the mode-map and use `C-k` and try different keys to see if it's avaialle

Comment: `C-h b` aka `M-x describe-bindings`?  See also Drew's answer for a library containing `describe-keymap`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7135736/2112489

Comment: In [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keymaps.html), you find the following advice about customizing key-bindings: "Key sequences that consist of `C-c` followed by a letter (upper or lower case; ASCII or non-ASCII) are reserved for users. Emacs itself will never bind those key sequences, and Emacs extensions should avoid binding them. In other words, users can bind key sequences like `C-c` a or `C-c ç` and rely on these never being shadowed by other Emacs bindings."

Comment: @lawlist I had `C-h b` bound to `helm-descbinds` and it was broken (package not downloaded) , I downloaded it and tried it. good ! thanks

Comment: @Tobias oh I didn't understand that sentence back when I read it, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Tobias I guess it's a good practice to use `C-c [:alpha]` as a prefix for a group of commands. Only `C-c` is special right? not `C-x` or anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Key Binding Conventions`

> How can I find out which keys are free to use for a mode-map?

Since Emacs 28.1, the standard command <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-keymap` shows the keybindings for the specified keymap.

You can *usually* get this same information from <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-mode`) although that isn't guaranteed (it depends on the docstring containing some particular syntax).

> The best way I can think of is to actually open a buffer with the mode-map and use C-k and try different keys to see if it's avaialle

It sounds like you're not really interested in a single mode map, but rather in knowing whether the key sequence in question is bound in *any* active keymap in the buffer?

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-bindings`) will show you all active bindings in the current buffer.

You can also use the `key-binding` function:

```
(key-binding KEY &optional ACCEPT-DEFAULT NO-REMAP POSITION)
 
Return the binding for command KEY in current keymaps.
KEY is a string or vector, a sequence of keystrokes.
The binding is probably a symbol with a function definition.
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `key-binding` for more.

Comment: Plus a couple of older Q&As of note: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59483 and (for Emacs versions older than 28.1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480173/

Comment: Why do you say that stackoverflow.com/questions/3480173 is for Emacs versions older than 28.1? It and the answers seem to apply still, AFAICT.

Comment: Just because 28.1 added a `describe-keymap` command.  (I'm sure the code in that answer does still work on later versions.)